# How does one label malicious traffic in generated workloads?

Tags: attacks, ids, wireshark

I have been writing on some code that automatically puts together differently parameterized attacks of common pen testing tools, i.e. sqlmap, nmap, patator etc. These attacks are then launched against two or three targets. I wanted to capture the traffic to generate a malicious workload that I can later use it as a trace. Long story short, my program puts together random attacks, so I never know which kind of attack is executed or when it arrives at my target, when the attack execution is over, etc. Is it somehow possible to correlate the attack traffic that leaves my computer to the traffic that is received by my targets? Can I somehow label these attacks or recognize them by byte patterns that leave my attacking system and arrive at the target systems? I am even not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but if anyone has any idea I would really appreciate some advice.

(If someone knows fitting tags for this kind of question, please let me know.)